# Why does openjdk automatically install when other version removed?

Tags: uninstall, openjdk

Every time I try to use **openjdk java 7**, nothing happens.  I try 6, and still, no response.

So, i tried removing it with Ubuntu Software Center.  Every time I click on "Remove", it appears to remove it, but then the other version automatically downloads.
For example, I remove *openjdk java 6*, and *java 7* (with all the add-ons) downloads onto my computer.  I go to delete that, and once 7 is removed, version 6 reinstalls automatically, with all the add-ons.

Anyone know where i can stop the automatic downloads so I can re-install openjdk java, and get my programs to run again?

Answer (score 1):

Something you installed is depending on Java (usually the package *java-common*). So you've got to have either one installed. You could also use Oracles Java packages (e.g. using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/173951/1736)). Then you can remove all OpenJDK (and IcedTea) packages like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk* icedtea*
```

You will keep the java-common package because Java is now provided by the sun-java* packages. If you want to entirely remove Java (and see which packages depend on it), try removing java-common.

Comment: @JonS., okay.. let me know if it works. If yes, please mark the question as answered. If not, tell us what happened.